# Use value from a form in a redirect button outside the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Fetch selected value from dropdown which is in one form and onClick of the button outside the form send the value to php page

```
<div class="drpvendorname">
      <font style="color: white;">
        <label>Distribution Point:</label>        
    </font>
    </div>
        <select class="form-control" id="drpvendor" name="pointname" required="">
        <option selected disabled>Choose distribution point</option>
         <?php
          $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM point_tbl ORDER BY pointname ASC";
          $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
          while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
          {          
            echo '<option onClick="distribution('.$result['pointshortname'].')" value="' .$result['pointshortname'].'">'. $result['pointname'].'</option>';
          }
          ?>
        </select>      
      </form><!--form1 ends here-->

      <form action="../customer/form.php"><!--form2 starts here-->
      <button class="btn pos7" name="abc" method="GET" style="margin-left:5%;">New Customer</button>
      </form><!--form2 ends here-->

      <div class="dailybreakupbtn">  
      <input class="btn" type="submit" id="dailybreakupbutn" name="dailybreakup" value="Enter Daily Breakup" onClick="distribution(<?=$pointname?>)"/>
      </div>
      <?php
      if(isset($pointname)){      
       ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function distribution(pointname){
          var pointname;
          window.location.href="dailybreakup.php?query=" +pointname;
        }
      </script>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
```

- I have tried this sending selected dropdown box value to next page using function name distribution
- I ended sending undefined to the next page.
- can any one help me sending the selected value to the next page with out putting the button in the `<form>`

Comment: can any one help me sending the selected value to the next page without putting the button in the form tag

Comment: create a onchange funtion on select and send data using ajax code

Comment: button id is dailybreakupbutn

Comment: KarthikeyanVivekanandhan and Gulshan how to do that iam new to ajax call

Answer (score 2):

May this will be help you :)
Html code:

```
<form action= "" method= "post">
<select class="form-control drpvendor" id="drpvendor" name="pointname" required="">
        <option selected disabled>Choose distribution point</option>
         <?php
          $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM point_tbl ORDER BY pointname ASC";
          $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
          while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
          {          
            echo '<option value="'.$result['pointshortname'].'">'. $result['pointname'].'</option>';
          }
          ?>
        </select> 
</form>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(doucment).on('change','.drpvendor',function(){
    var data=$(this).attr('selected','selected');
      $.ajax({
      url: "dailybreakup.php",
      data:'query='+ data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
         window.location.href='customer/form.php';
      }
      });
    });
```

Comment: here how will i get the drop down box value...?

Comment: please help me out iam not getting where to put the select box id or name and button id or name?

Comment: @Avinash replace your select html with this line <select class="form-control" id="drpvendor" name="pointname" required="" onChange=dailybreakup(this)>

Comment: there is no need of button now.just place your select in form and remove action of form

Comment: onChange=dailybreakup(this.value)

Comment: I need the button because if i click the button enter daily breakup it has to navigate to next page with the selected option value

Comment: clicking the button its not navigating to other page

Answer (score 0):

Use  code

```
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> // please link the path or use cdn 
<script type="text/javascript">
function call_me(){
    var pointname=document.getElementById("drpvendor").value;
    alert(pointname); // comment it after testing 
    window.location.href="dailybreakup.php?query=" +pointname;
}
</script>
<form>
    <select class="form-control" id="drpvendor" name="pointname" required="">
    <option selected disabled>Choose distribution point</option>
     <?php
      $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM point_tbl ORDER BY pointname ASC";
      $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
      while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {          
        echo '<option  value="' .$result['pointshortname'].'">'. $result['pointname'].'</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>  
   <input type="button" onclick="call_me()"/>       
  </form><!--form1 ends here-->

    Note : 1) Code is not tested 
           2) use your select id instead of your_select_id
           3)  check variable
```

Comment: i have mailed you .